# Get a method with a single or no attributes with Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm learning Reflection and I'm working on a serializeable action type which can be saved and then loaded and triggered. The serializeable action supports methods without parameters or a single parameter of type int, float, double, string or bool.

**All** of the methods which names are passed either have **one attribute** of the above-listed types or have **no attributes** at all they could also have one attribute that has a default value. 
And here come my problems. First of all I get an AmbiguousMatchException when I call `target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);`for a method that has overloads and I get a NULL if I call it for a method with a single optional parameter.

So what I do right now is start with a try-catch to catch the AmbiguousMatchException which then tells me that the given method has overloads. If I get an exception, I start trying to get the method passing arrays of different attribute types to search for:

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethod(string methodName, Object _target)
    {
        try
        {
            MethodInfo info = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
            return info;
        }
        catch (AmbiguousMatchException ex)
        {
            MethodInfo info = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new System.Type[0]);
            if (info != null) return info;
            info = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(int) });
            if (info != null) return info;
            info = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(float) });
            if (info != null) return info;
            info = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(double) });
            if (info != null) return info;
            info = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(string) });
            if (info != null) return info;
            info = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(bool) });
            return info;
        }
    }
```

This is extremely ugly but it works okay for the overloaded methods. However it returns NULL if the method has an optional parameter. I tried using the OptionalParamBinding binding flag but that returned NULL even for methods whithout overloads and a single optional parameter.

So my question is:
How can I go about that? I need this static method to find:
 - An overload of the method with an int, float, double, string or bool parameter
 - If that fails, an overload with an optional int, float, double, string or bool parameter
 - And if that fails, the overload without any parameters

Comment: You could use `GetMethods` instead and loop until you find a match. Personally though, if I needed a specific method, I would be asking for the type of parameters that were expected to help find the correct method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific requirements, it's pretty easy to do that in a LINQ query.

```
var validParameterTypes = new HashSet<Type> { typeof(int), typeof(float), ... };

var methods = from method in _target.GetType().GetMethods()
              let parameters = method.GetParameters()
              let hasParameters = parameters.Length > 0
              let firstParameter = hasParameters ? parameters[0] : null
              let isOptionalParameter = (hasParameters && firstParameter.IsOptional) ? true : false
              where method.Name == methodName &&
                    (!hasParameters || validParameterTypes.Contains(firstParameter.ParameterType))
              orderby parameters.Length descending, isOptionalParameter
              select method;
```

At which point you evaluate the methods as they come out of the query and see if they meet your needs.

There's a different question, though, and that is "*should* I do things this way?". TyCobb has already mentioned this in his comment, and he's correct.

The current way you're attempting to do things is a lot of work for no immediate gain. So you get a list of overloads, that doesn't really help you. Now you have to do overload resolution yourself and find the "best" overload to call (or just take the first one you find, but that could break very easily if methods are added/removed/changed).

Let's assume that you also stored the parameter type (if any) that you are looking for. Knowing that will condense your code down to this:

```
var parameterTypes = (knownParameterType == null ) ? Type.EmptyTypes : new[] { knownParameterType };
var method = _target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
```

Easier, cleaner, and more obviously correct! You don't even have to check for allowed parameter types here, make them do that as a part of constructing a valid "action type" that you're defining.